# .htaccess redirect from one folder to another but exclude subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess I want to redirect all traffic from http://mywebsite.com/oldfolder   to  http://mywebsite.com/newfolder/#/something/

This should include any url parts that come after the folder part.  e.g http://mywebsite.com/oldfolder/abc   to http://mywebsite.com/newfolder/#/something/abc

I tried using this

```
RedirectMatch 301 /oldfolder/(.*) /newfolder/#/something/$1
```

This kind of works but now some of my other paths don't work as 'oldfolder'  happend to be the name of a subfolder.  e.g http://mywebsite.com/someotherfolder/oldfolder/something
The rule appears to be trying to redirect this as well but I would like it be ignored. I only want it to redirect if 'oldfolder' is a root folder.

What change do I need to make to the rule for this to work?

Comment: You cannot rewrite to a URL with a `#` in it. Better practice is to rewrite all to `index.php` and use PHP to analize the REQUEST_URI ans show the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `mod_rewrite` rule instead of rule shown in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^oldfolder/(.*)$ /newfolder/#/something/$1 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

- `^` will make sure `oldfolder/` matches only at root.
- `NE` flag will encode `#` in redirected URL.

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this.

Comment: I tried this, but now no route works at all.  
Even routes to css files don't work.
e.g http://mywebsite.com/someotherfolder/style.css

Comment: See update and also make sure this is first rule before any other rule.

Comment: That still didn't work.  The rule appears to  effects all folder.  I just want to target /oldfolder

Comment: If this rule is in `oldfolder/.htaccess` then **there is no way** it can affect any other folder. Make sure you completely clear browser cache and also make sure there is no other rule in root .htaccess or Apache config.

Comment: ok cool, but there isn't a physical oldfolder folder.  It's just a route.

Comment: Aha, you didn't mention it before. I am reverting my change, can you also copy/paste your complete root .htaccess in question.